# zeroupper causes incorrect results

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, avx, avx2

I have a following code inside a for loop

```
    dataInt = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *) (&x[i]));
    __m256i val_unpacked = _mm256_cvtepi16_epi32(dataInt);
    __m256 converted = _mm256_cvtepi32_ps(val_unpacked);

    converted = _mm256_div_ps(converted, _mm256_set1_ps(max_val));

    _mm256_storeu_ps(&y[i], converted);
    _mm256_zeroupper();
```

It basically just converts vector of int16 to floats in range [-1,1] (max_val is const variable and equal to  numeric_limit::max).

I'm using mingw compiler with posix thread version 7.2

When I compile the program without optimisation, it runs just fine, but when I turn on optimisation (I do not have control over the individual optimisations, it is inside a project I am working on, but it should be using lvl of optimisation -O3 ), I start to get wrong results.

The problem is in the zeroupper instruction. When I remove it in mode with optimisations, it again gives correct results.

Seemingly the optimisation does not respect the placement of the zeroupper instruction and calls it somewhere in the middle of the loop and not at the very end, thus discarding useful data. Is something like that possible? I could not find any discussion regarding this topic on the internet.

EDIT: I extracted the code. It looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>  
 int  __attribute__ ((__target__ ("avx2,sse4.2"))) main(){

/*volatile*/ float max_val = static_cast<float> (std::numeric_limits<int16_t>::max());

__m128i dataInt;
int runs = 32;
int16_t source[32];
float target[32];
int i = 0;
for (; i < 32; ++i) {
    source[i] = std::numeric_limits<int16_t>::min()+i;
}

i=0;
for (; i < runs; i += 8) {
    // _mm256_zeroupper();

     dataInt = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *) (&source[i]));

      __m256i val_unpacked =_mm256_cvtepi16_epi32(dataInt);
    __m256 converted =  _mm256_cvtepi32_ps(val_unpacked);

    __m256 maxVinFloat = _mm256_set1_ps(max_val);
    converted = _mm256_div_ps(converted, maxVinFloat);

    _mm256_storeu_ps(&target[i], converted);
    _mm256_zeroupper();
}
i = 0;
for (; i < 32; ++i) {
    std::cout << target [ i ] <<"  ";
}}
```

However when compiled on online compilers, the output is fine, even when using lvl 3 optimisation. But my Clion using compiler described in my original post outputs several infinities, because the register maxVinFloat with max values is composed of zeroes in one half of the register. So,it seems the register is optimised to be initialised only once and other iterations of the cycle output infinities.

EDIT2: My mistake, it does output infinities on online compilers, but I forgot to remove the volatile part (that fixes the problem) when testing it,  just run that code 
here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php with -O2 optimisation

Comment: You normally never need to manually insert a `_mm256_zeroupper()`.  Compilers insert the `vzeroupper` asm instruction as needed.  But still an interesting question; I would have expected GCC to respect `_mm256_zeroupper()` placement in the source and treat it as zeroing the top half of every ``__m256` that was in scope at the time.  Can you add enough C++ code to the question to make a [mcve] we can copy/paste into a compiler, e.g. on https://godbolt.org/, and look at the asm output?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82735

Comment: @PeterCordes Working on it, but seems that extracting the code removes the problem. It is going to take a lot more time (that I do not currently have). My original intention was just to scan my options quickly, to get information whether some else dealt with this before or whether it is known to be a problem. But seems I am gonna have to dig a lot deeper.

Comment: @PeterCordes I added the extracted version of the function.